# ¿Estoy saturando mi base de datos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Actualmente tengo corriendo 3 (tres) aplicaciones de escritorio las cuales consultan 1 (una) vez por minuto una base de datos para saber si hay novedades en la misma.
La base de datos está alojada en un hosting de un sitio web (tengo la DB del sitio web propio y otra DB para este fin)

El motor de base de datos es MySQL

Mi consulta es si ¿estaré saturando la DB con 3 consultas por minuto? (es solo un SELECT). 
¿Que otra alternativa tengo al polling para saber si hay novedades en la base de datos?

Comment: haz tenido errores? que aparece en el log de tu servidor?  tu pull de conexiones como esta configurado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mi consulta es si ¿estaré saturando la DB con 3 consultas por minuto?

La respuesta es:

## NO

Tres consultas por minuto a MySQL son un chiste, un paseo en el parque, un pan con mantequilla. Las bases de datos están pensadas para procesar una cantidad muchísimo mayor de peticiones.

Ahora, no te dejes engañar por lo que acabo de decir. Solo mencionas que haces un `SELECT` y esto lo haces ver como si fuera una consulta relativamente sencilla. Hay algunas cosas que tener en cuenta, como por ejemplo:

- ¿Cuántos registros tiene la tabla?, ¿está indexada?
- ¿Qué tan complejo es el query?, ¿haces algunos `JOIN`s?
- ¿Cuándo haces la consulta toma mucho tiempo en obtener una respuesta?

Si es un query sencillo en una tabla relativamente pequeña (algunos miles de registros), entonces no tienes de qué preocuparte y no necesitas complicarte la vida con otras cosas. Sigue usando el polling.